# SPFX ClientSideAssets folder and dist folders have old code

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp, react-webpart

When I build my solution, minified JS files have my old lines. Here are my steps:

1 - gulp clean
2 - gulp build
3 - gulp bundle
4 - gulp package-solution --ship

file under \dist\test-web-part.js
file under \sharepoint\solution\debug\ClientSideAssets\test-web-part_7b75e81b5de1ea7a45c0575c9bfcde29.js

They both get updated with my old code. I delete these files and they re-created with the old code again.
I see old console.log lines in the minified js.

I do not have much experience in SPFX development. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Aslan, is there any updates ? Did you try the solution below, if it helps to solve the problem, you could accept as answer so that it could also help other in the forum :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the guide for deploying SPFX solution:

[Build And Deploy The Client Side Web Part (SPFx) In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-and-deploy-the-client-side-web-part-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/)

Should upload the files under project folder - Temp - deploy to the library:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to Run bundle with `--ship` attribute when you need to make a deployment package.The `--ship` indicates the build tool to build for distribution.
So it should be

```
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```